# DynamoDB extra table to keep inactive data

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Does it make sense in DynamoDB to store inactive / expired data in a separate table to cut cost (scans / queries)?

My plan is to have object with 7 day TTL. When item is removed from DynamoDB it will trigger a Lambda that will put removed record to a new table (not frequently scanned / queried). Or it doesn't really make any difference and i should keep everything in one place?

thanks!

Comment: Can you give some idea of the number of records in the main table and estimate of how much you think you can move to the archive table per month? That can help present a better cost benefit analysis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how your queries look. If you do a `scan`/`query` with filters, then all items read will cost, even if not returned.

If you do a full table scan for a regular cleanup, for example, it's worth separating the tables.

If you are accessing your data by (index) hash key (and sort key), which do not match any inactive data, then it shouldn't matter.